# Mockito @SpyBean annotation conflict with SpringRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

I am currently trying to create a partial mock of a repository, but I am running into issues whenever I try to annotate the JDBC repository with SpyBean.

```
@RunsWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = ServiceApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
public abstract class TestBase {

    @SpyBean
    protected JdbcRepository jdbcRepository;

    @Before
    public void baseSetUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
        this.testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);

        this.classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        ...
    }
```

When I run the application, I get the following message:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not inject field: protected com.sample.app.JdbcRepository cannot have an existing value

However, I have found a few ways to avoid the error:

- When "@RunsWith(SpringRunner.class)" is removed, the tests seem to run fine. However, a lot of the documentation that I have read seems to indicate that this is required
- Added "@SpyBean(JdbcRepository.class)" and autowiring jdbcRepository also seems to work. Perhaps this is a context issue where it is trying to instantiate an instance of JdbcRepository multiple times?

In short, I am not sure why my test is throwing the BeanCreationException. Is the @SpyBean annotation above the class member not the correct way of using spy beans?

Comment: try again without this line `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: Nope, same error.

Comment: Why are you bypassing/hacking the `TstContext` framework? You are basically doing all the work again that has already been done? Why. You are trying to outsmart the framework and that is what it biting you. Basically remove your `baseSetUp` all together (or at least the part which you interfere with Mockito and the Spring Test Confext framework.

Comment: I believe the reason why I am making the call to TestContext is because and I am attempting to use this base class for both parameterized and non-parameterized test cases. Does this mean that if I don't run the test with SpringRunner, I don't need the logic in baseSetUp?